# Flask 400 Bad request KeyError

Tags: python, flask

My code for the flask server is this,

```py
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

todos = {}

@app.route('/<todo_id>', methods=['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
def main(todo_id):
  if request.method == 'GET':
    try:
      return {todo_id: todos[todo_id]}
    except:
      return {"status": "paused or off"}
  elif request.method == 'DELETE':
    if todo_id in todos:
      del todos[todo_id]
      return '', 204
    else:
      return '', 404
  elif request.method == 'PUT':
      json = {"modules": request.form['modules'],
      "hits":request.form['hits'],
      "customs":request.form['customs'],
      "free":request.form['free'],
      "bads":request.form['bads'],
      "checked":request.form['checked'],
      "remaining":request.form['remaining'],
      "retries":request.form['retries'],
      "errors":request.form['errors'],
      "cpm":request.form['cpm']
      }
      print(1)
      todos[todo_id] = json
      print(1)
      return {todo_id: todos[todo_id]}

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080, debug=True)
```

And my client code is like this,

```
import requests

params = (
    ('cpm', '123'),
        ("modules", "doordash|COD"),
        ("hits", '63242'),
        ("customs", "888"),
        ("free", "233"),
        ("bads", "3892"),
        ("checked", '20000'),
        ("remaining", '200000'),
        ("retries", "1000"),
        ("errors", '1234')
        )
response = requests.put('https://animeaskedforitt.my name.repl.co/123?modules=edigubv', params=params)
print(response)
r = requests.get("https://animeaskedforitt.myname.repl.co/123").text
print(r)
```

Every time I run it I get a 500 error from the put request and a 200 succes code.

In the console I get a 400 error saying “bad request” and a python error of `KeyError: module`

Thanks for your help

Comment: I think you should use `data` kwarg instead of `params` in this put request and I think there's no need to put `?modules=edigbuv` at the end of the URL. Also, you have a typo in this URL - a space in `my name`

Comment: Thanks! The data param fixed it!